# communication between bluetooth module and remote Human interface device

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, uart

I have been using bluetooth module BC 417 of company "NOVA".
I have kept all UART setting as suggested by datasheet.
i.e. `buad rate=9600`, `parity=none`, `stop bit=1`

My connection is getting established with nokia 5130 bluetooth, but as soon as m going to send something from UART connection is disabled. 
Whenever i go to connect this module to android phone's bluetooth, connection does not take place.

For making connection i am using this command `BC:CS=<address of bluetooth>`

So i have following question:-

1. Is there any another setting is required in hyper terminal?
2. Is there any firmware is available for nova comm control interface module version 1.2?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I only have enough reputation to answer and not just comment. You might want to try making sure that hardware flow control is switched on. It's a little difficult to know for sure as details of your set-up are so sketchy. Are you connecting this to an embedded micro and then trying to connect to a phone? What are you connecting hyper terminal to? Another phone or this Nova module?